# Testing to see if an event is running with jest

Tags: events, jestjs, event-handling

I'm trying to think of a scenario to actually test if the event is running. Here's how my brain is working. I register a listener and I'm expecting spy to be called, but it's not?

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
const ee = new EventEmitter()

describe('Event Emitter', () => {
  it('Emit Listener', () => {
    ee.on('test', function() {})   
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ee, 'on')

    ee.emit('test')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jest.spyOn(ee, 'on')` sets a spy that can test if `ee.on(...)` has been called after that. Since it wasn't, the test fails. There is no way a spy could be retroactive. Instead, it should be set before it's called:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(ee, 'on')
ee.on('test', function() {})   

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function))
```

Or if the objective is to test the event, it should be:

```
const spy = jest.fn()
ee.on('test', spy)
ee.emit('test')

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```